# Choosing Between Prism and Caliburn

Tags: prism, caliburn

I have been using Prism 2.0 for a personal project for a few months now. I have recently heard of Caliburn and am wondering if there are compelling reasons for me to consider that instead.

I like Prism's dynamic module loading capability. I intend to build modules for my application and would like to be able to deploy them in a modular manner. Is that also possible with Caliburn?

What are the advantages of Caliburn over Prism?

(I read that Prism will also have a new version by September 2010 that will leverage .Net 4.0. and am keeping my application flexible to be updated by then as well.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Prism and Caliburn are complimentary frameworks.  Caliburn really enables a lot of the things that are shortcomings when you focus on MVVM in WPF and Prism allows that nice modularity (among other things).  This is a simplification (both have way more features than just that), but it's the major reason you'd want to combine them.

Caliburn has builtin Prism support so you can use both.  Here's an article I found of someone using the integration to setup their first module.
http://rauhski.blogspot.com/2009/10/build-application-with-caliburn-and.html

Also, if you download Caliburn, there is a sample included that demonstrates the Prism integration.

Comment: does anybody know the rigth url?